# Definite integral reciprocal of polynomial plus trig function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{x^{1/4}+\cos x}$$

What are the steps to integrate?

Comment: This doesn't look improper, the denominator is bounded below.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that a solution exists? Where did this problem come from?

Comment: $x^{1/4}$ is definitively not a polynomial... And, however, the integrand seems not to be elementary integrable. Neverthless, the definite integral exists (because the integrand is everywhere continuous in $[0,\pi/2]$), it is a positive real number (for the integrand is positive in $[0,\pi/2]$) and it approximately equals $1$. ;-)

Comment: $$\int_0^{{\pi}/{2}}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt[4]{x}+\cos x}\approx1.0404304336753636$$

Answer (score 0):

By using the formula http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/7/2/a/72a1058ad2087aec467af24bddcf9479.png, we have $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{dx}{x^\frac{1}{4}+\cos x}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^{2^n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+1}}{2^n\left(\dfrac{m^\frac{1}{4}\pi^\frac{1}{4}}{2^\frac{n+1}{4}}+\cos\dfrac{m\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)}$

Comment: What is this formula called?